# Getting info from an ACTUAL table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to learn coding while making "programs" that help me at work.  I have been rather successful at making these "programs" that output a mathematical value, but I want to progress to "tables."

I have several "tables" that I use at work.  I want to make HTML/Javascript to give me the "answer" from a table by just telling it the 2 "variables" and it telling me what that value is...

I don't even know how to ask this question so I knwo WHAT to learn, So I am here getting advice.

I can make a table, but how do I tell the program to "get" the info I want?

What do I study to be able to make my website return the answer "13" when someone selects "green" from dropdown menu #1 and "a" from dropdown menu #2?  Or answer "2" when the user selects "red" and "b"? etc. etc. etc...

```
<table border="1">
<tr>
  <td></td>
  <td>a</td>
  <td>b</td>
  <td>c</td>
  <td>d</td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td>red</td>
  <td>01</td>
  <td>02</td>
  <td>03</td>
  <td>04</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>yellow</td>
  <td>05</td>
  <td>06</td>
  <td>07</td>
  <td>08</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>blue</td>
  <td>09</td>
  <td>10</td>
  <td>11</td>
  <td>12</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>green</td>
  <td>13</td>
  <td>14</td>
  <td>15</td>
  <td>16</td>
</tr>

</table>
```

Comment: if i were you, i would look into jQuery's traversal and selector methods, which will do 90% of the frustrating work in your question for you. once you learn how to author the correct hard-coded css selectors and get them to work in firebug, wiring the selector argument to some text boxes is pretty simple.

Comment: spend a bunch of time in the jQuery API as @dandavis suggests...there are examples for every method

Comment: I know NOTHING of jQuery... is there a way to do a similar thing with html/css/javascript... maybe not "pick from a table," but use "if" statements or something.  I'm not "locked-in" in picking from a table, I just want to output the information onto the web page (even if it means writing a bunch of code)

Comment: yes, anything jQuery can do, so can vanilla JS. it's just that your question can be answered with 1 or 2 lines of jQuery and 10-20 lines of normal JS, more if you care about xbrowser support. if you want to embed data into html, you can use json to ship the data and something like mustache or even more advanced like knockout to inject the data into the HTML. if you must do it all yourself, review the DOM pages on mdn, take a pain killer, and start writing code. if you have an attempt, even feeble, you're get more and better feedback here.